# "Function.createDelegate" causes "Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'createDelegate'"

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am trying to get browser back button support in silverlight by following [this](http://jakkaj.wordpress.com/2008/09/08/control-silverlight-by-using-browser-back-and-foward-buttons/) tutorial.
I am using Silverlight 4, Asp and .net4.0.

I am not very used to javascript and compared to C# I never really liked working with it.

The error message I am reciving is this: "Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'createDelegate'"

on this line

```js
//Create a delegate to preserve scope when the navigation event handler fires.
var handler = Function.createDelegate(historyInstance, historyInstance.navigationEventHandler);
```

My first guess is that some reference is missing but when searching I found nothing!

What is the cause of this error message?
Please look at the tutorial for full source code.

Answer (score 0):

The standard `Function` class does not have the method `createDelegate`. It's either supported by the browser or defined by an external library.

Consider Ext's [bind](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.Function-method-bind) or jQuery's [proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/).

Answer (score 0):

Natively you can do it with `func.apply`:

```
var handler = historyInstance.navigationEventHandler.apply(historyInstance);
```

Take a look at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) for more details.